# Can I prearrange my troops before battle?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

The default arrangement of my troops at the start of battle is...suboptimal.  For example, I'd prefer to start with my ranged units directly behind my melee units, but instead they tend to start off to one side.

Is there any way to arrange my troops before battle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have some effect on it by [changing the order of the units on your hero sheet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32453/where-on-the-tactical-map-are-specific-army-stacks-placed).  But the Tactics skill lets you place your units wherever you want before the battle starts.  Taking this allows you to put your archers in a corner and surround them with melee units from the start.

Tactics is in the Realm tree.  The upgraded version allows you to place guys closer to your opponent.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any more information on which skill it is / how I can get it?

Comment: I added a screenshot of where to find it (there are a ridiculous number of skills in this game, I still have only read about half of them!)